# Rails query not equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails app has 3 components:
-users (has many works and comments)
-works (blog posts) (belongs to users, has many comments)
-comments (comments belong to both users and work)

I'm trying to display all the comments on a page for a particular user **except comments made on blog posts that belong to him/her**. What should my query look like in the controller?

Here is what I have so far. It does not load any comments at all.

```
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @works = Work.pluck(:user_id)
    @comments = @user.comments.where(is_boolean_value: true).where(['user_id NOT IN(?)', @works]).all
```

How can I change this query so that shows all comments made by a user where the user did not own the work?

Thanks!
-b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is the

```
Work.pluck(:user_id)
```

That fetches the user_id for any user that has an object of table Work.  Instead, fetch the work ids for the items the user created:

```
@works = @user.works.map {|obj| obj.id}
```

Then ask the database to give you all the comments that belong to that user but do not belong to one of his works:

```
@comments = @user.comments.where('work_id NOT IN(?)', @works)
```

Comment: That worked! Can you please explain the @works query? What does the .map and obj do? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: That fetches all the works that belongs to the user.  .map turns one array into another.  So for each element in works, it calls it obj, then it returns the obj.id.  Basically @works is now full of the work ids that belong to that particular user.

Comment: Thanks again! I really appreciate the explanation :)